# How to make AutoComplete Google-API specific to city

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

How to make AutoComplete Google-API specific to city [Not Country]

I have searched many questions on StackOverflow but didn't find the answer that works specifically to the country 
I wanna make my placepi (autocomplete) specific to city search, for now, I have made it specific to country but I also want to make it to **city-specific search**

Here is my code:

```
        private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
        private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
        private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + "API_KEY");
        sb.append("&types=establishment");
        sb.append("&types=street_address");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
        sb.append("&components=" + country_code);
        sb.append("&components=administrative_area_level_3:" + city_name);
```

PS: I have checked the code by adding below the line but didn't get search inside the city
*&components=administrative_area_level_3:" + city_name*

I also check it with *locale*

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to restrict Places Autocomplete results to specific cities/localities. As a workaround for now, you can bias the autocomplete results to favor an approximate location or area as stated in this **[documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#location_biasing)**.

There is also an existing feature request to filter using route, locality, administrative_area, postal_code and country in the Places API autocomplete. I'd recommend you comment your use-case in there and "star" it to receive updates. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822067

Hope this helps!